# How can I Achieve the following output with dynamic input values?

Tags: c#

In my office there was a jackpot programming event was conducted, in that event they asked 3 questions, but 1 of the puzzles was really tough for us and I just tried in my own interest

**Question:**

```
A = {10, 15, 25}
B = {1, 5, 20, 30}
```

**Expected output:**

```
10 20
10 20 25 30
10 30
15 20
15 20 25 30
15 30
25 30
```

In output:

- 10 20 --> A's 1st element and B's 1st smallest element that greater than A's 1st element
- 10 20 25 30 --> A's 1st element Check with B array, which is greater than A, and again Check with A , repeat it until B doesn't have any greater element in compared to A, if B doesn't have to end up with previous B value.
- 10 30 --> A's 1st element and B's largest element that greater than A's 1st element

the above method will iterate all over the A elements.

Comment: `Each set should be unique.` What does it mean? Define precisely.

Comment: Each set means 10 20 is one set, 10 20 25 30 one set like this we called this as a Set.
This must be unique.

Comment: Define uniqueness of your set. Not what set is.

Comment: Kindly observe the logic of the question and given output.

Comment: Can you give me exactly how and what the question was asked instead of your own observations?

Comment: @AMunim, this is a logical question, I need to achieve the output to gain knowledge that's the reason I've posted here. I didn't find any brief question anywhere for this, I have only the small piece.

Comment: Just to be clear. The only original things are set A, B, and the expected output? these are the things you were given to work with

Comment: @AMunim, yes, I can understand, but these things only I have, and also i shared my understanding in the question above.

Comment: @AMunim, Thanks, Please go ahead. Eagerly waiting for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood your problem correctly it is like this

```
class Solution
{
    int[] a;
    int[] b;

    public Solution(int[] a, int[] b)
    {
        this.a = a;
        this.b = b;
    }

    void InterateA(int min, string output)
    {
        foreach (var a in a.OrderBy(n => n).SkipWhile(n => n <= min))
        {
            InterateB(a, $"{output}\t{a}");
        }
    }

    void InterateB(int min, string output)
    {
        foreach (var b in b.OrderBy(n => n).SkipWhile(n => n <= min))
        {
            var str = $"{output} {b}";
            Console.WriteLine(str);
            InterateA(b, str);
        }
        output = null;
    }

    public void Print()
    {
        InterateA(a.OrderBy(n => n).First() - 1, null);
    }
}
```

Test code

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var a = new int[] { 10, 15, 25, 35 };
    var b = new int[] { 1, 5, 20, 30, 40 };
    var solution = new Solution(a, b);
    solution.Print();
    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

Performance is minimum as this is initial trivial solution and canbe optimized if it does the job correctly.

Comment: When I add 35 in A and 40 in B , got lot of duplicates and order goes wrong. Nice try..

Comment: `order goes wrong` Give the correct order.

Comment: Kindly see my question i just now updated, order depends on {A} array elements order.

Comment: See my code update. I made a change.

Comment: Awesome.., well if the starting intended will avoid. Thanks for your precious time to answer this.

Comment: You are welcome. As I already said performance is minimum as this is initial trivial solution and canbe optimized if it does the job correctly. So I leave it to you as a homework.

Comment: Is my question is readable and understandable now?

Answer (score 2):

Here is my solution, the only thing that didn't make sense was why he skipped 15 in the first set of sets, and since you don't have any more information I had to suppose the reason for skipping it(call it an exception)

```
int[] A = { 10, 15, 25 };
int[] B = { 1, 5, 20, 30 };
//10 20
//10 20 25 30
//10 30
//15 20
//15 20 25 30
//15 30
//25 30

var result = A.SelectMany(x => GetIllogicalPermutations(x, A, B)).DistinctBy(x => x.Sum());
for (int i = 0; i < result.Count(); i++)
{
    Console.WriteLine(string.Join(' ', result.ElementAt(i).Select(x => x.ToString())));
}

Console.ReadLine();

static IEnumerable<int[]> GetIllogicalPermutations(int item, int[] setA, int[] setB)
{
    yield return new int[] { item, setB.Where(x => x > item).Min() };
    yield return setA.Where(x => x > item && x != (setA.Max() - setA.Min())).Concat(setB.Where(x => x > item)).Prepend(item).OrderBy(x => x).ToArray();
    yield return new int[] { item, setB.Where(x => x > item).Max() };
}
```

Comment: Actually the logic for 10 20 25 30 is you must start with A and Check B and Check with A,
When B doesn't have any greater values you need to end up with your previous B value.

Comment: There was an compilation error your code, (DistinctBy) ?

Comment: That logic is your own not specified in the question

Comment: Are you `using System.Linq`?

Comment: Yes. using this using System.Linq; namespace

Comment: try `.Distinct()`, If you can't get that then create a `Hashset` out of them that'll get you unique items

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/245223/discussion-between-amunim-and-mohideen-asraf).